# MySQL 5.5 Alter Table TimeStamp default to Current Value, but it's being set to 0 instead

Tags: mysql, timestamp, alter-table, alter

I am trying to add a `last_updated` column to a table w/ preexisting data in it. After I execute the `ALTER TABLE` statement, I expect for the `last_updated` column for all existing data to be set to the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD COLUMN last_updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

However, the value is set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for all preexisting rows. Any subsequent inserts are created with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as expected.

I am using MySQL 5.5. Are my expectations incorrect here? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is an old bug [Bug #68040: ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP still inserts zero](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68040), solved from version 5.6.11 [Changes in MySQL 5.6.11 (04/18/2013)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-11.html).

In 5.5, with a [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) can avoid the problem with some more code.

Example:

```sql
SET @`ddl` := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `TableName`
                   ADD COLUMN `last_updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
                   DEFAULT \'', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '\'
                   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;');
PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`ddl`;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;

ALTER TABLE `TableName`
MODIFY COLUMN `last_updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7233ee/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the link to the bug!